# How to print plain text in CGI?

Tags: perl

I'm using `HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI`

```
 print $cgi->header("text/plain"),
       $cgi->start_html("Hello"),
       $cgi->h1("Hello $who!"),
       $cgi->end_html;
```

Is there something like `$cgi->start_text("hello")`?

I want to output plain text.

Comment: Note that the documentation for CGI says this *“CGI.pm is no longer considered good practice for developing web applications,* ***including quick prototyping and small web scripts.*** *There are far better, cleaner, quicker, easier, safer, more scalable, more extensible, more modern alternatives available at this point in time. These [are] documented with [`CGI::Alternatives`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives)”*.

Comment: If you want to output plain text, then don't print out HTML :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just print it...

```
 print $cgi->header("text/plain"),
       "hello";
```